# need assistance witth implementing facebook sdk into AppDelegate.m file

Tags: xcode

Currently I'm trying to add the following to my appdelegate.m according to facebook:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    // Add any custom logic here.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    openURL:(NSURL *)url 
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
        openURL:url
            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
            annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
            ];

  // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled;
}
```

---

My current file looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"back"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

---

When I insert the code it looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    // Add any custom logic here.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                    ];

    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled;




    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"back"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

**Xcode tells me the** [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"back"]; **code will never be executed.**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

My appDelegate.m looks like theis and I don't have your error

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  // Firebase configurations
  [FIRApp configure];

  // Facebook SDK
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}



// FACEBOOK SDK
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```